# Can not find name 'myobject' Angular2

Tags: angular

i've got problems with angular2 v. 2.4.0, when I try to import class, it calls me that TS2304:Cannot find name 'HTTPTestService' (Name of the class) the code component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PictureRegister } from '../student.data';
import { HTTPTestService } from 'json.service';
@Component({
moduleId: module.id.toString(),
    selector: 'student-register',
    templateUrl: 'student-register.component.html',
    providers: [
        PictureRegister,
        HTTPTestService
    ]
})
export class StudentRegisterComponent {
    constructor( 
                 pictureRegister: PictureRegister,
                 httpJSON: HTTPTestService //Here is error
)
```

and service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class HTTPTestService{
    constructor (_http: Http)
    {
        this.httpJSON = _http;
    }
//etc
}
```

I also got second class file, which works well, but I dont want to put all classes into that, can you help me ?

Comment: Because you import it  badly. Try using `import {HTTPTestService} from './service.ts';`

Comment: The file is called json.service.ts?

Answer (score 1):

```
import { HTTPTestService } from './json.service';
```